# Multiplying N positive odd numbers

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the product of N positive odd numbers

```
function multOdd(n) {
  var mult = 1;
  var counter=[];

  for (var i = 1; i <= 2*n-1; i += 2){
    counter.push(i);
  }

  console.log(counter);
  return mult=mult*counter[i];
}                

console.log(multOdd(10));
```

I pushed the numbers into an array and attempted to get the product from them but I can't get it to work.

Comment: `mult = mult * counter[i]` performs **one** multiplication operation. You don't need the array at all; just multiply the accumulator by each odd number.

Comment: i want to mention that i get the correct numbers (the first 10 odd numbers) and i push them successfully into the array. My issue is with the array and why i can't get the produce of the numbers in the array.

Comment: So, you just really need to [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) all the elements on the array to one, right?

Comment: @Pointy if i attempt to multiply like "return mult=mult*i;" i will get the result 21. This is not right since the first 10 odd numbers are [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19] and my N is 10

Comment: @msg can i use the reduce function to multiply the contents in the array?

Comment: instead of putting them all into an array, just keep multiplying `mult` by `i`. In the loop, just do `mult *= i`. At the end, `return mult` (remove the current `return` statement that you have).

Comment: Yeah, you just need the proper reducer function.

Comment: @SamCreamer thank you Sam, that helped me. :D

Comment: @ZiatcoFelix my pleasure, good luck

Comment: There are a lot of good and correct answers and i will check them carefully so i can learn to approach this issue from different sides. Thank you all for the quick answers, i appreciate your help and knowledge !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you return `mult=mult*counter[i]` you're only returning the multipication once. It should return `mult = 1 * counter[lastElement+2]` which will be wrong. In your case, the last element of counter is 19, before exiting for loop i value is i= 19 + 2 = 21. You're returning mult = 1 * 21 = 21.

You can instead return the multipication value by for loop with no need for an array:

```
function multOdd(n) {
  var mult = 1;

  for (var i = 1; i <= 2*n-1; i += 2){
    mult = mult * i;
  }

  return mult;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the result for n, use:

```
function multOdd(n) {
  var result = 1;

  for (var i = 1; i <= 2*n-1; i += 2){
    result = result * i;
  }

  console.log(result);
  return result;
}                

console.log(multOdd(4));
```

If you want an array that has an array indexed by the number of odd numbers up to n you could use:

```
function multOdd(n) {
  let result = 1;
  let results = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 2*n-1; i += 2){
    result = result * i;
    results[(i+1) / 2] = result;
  }

  console.log(results);
  return results;
}                

console.log(multOdd(10));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to get the product of an array of numbers.  Here are two easy ones:
Relevant [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
// Using `Array.prototype.reduce`
[3, 5, 7, 9].reduce((acc, val) => acc * val)

// Using a `for ... of` loop
let product = 1
for (const val of [3, 5, 7, 9]) {
  product *= val
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could separate out the two steps of your current code into two functions:

```js
const getFirstNOddNums = (n) => {
  let oddNums = []
  for (let i = 1; i <= 2*n-1; i+=2) {
    oddNums.push(i)
  }
  return oddNums
}

const productOfArray = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((a, b) => a * b)
}

const N = 5
const firstNOddNums = getFirstNOddNums(N)
console.log(`The first ${N} odd numbers are: ${JSON.stringify(firstNOddNums)}`)
console.log(`The product of the first ${N} odd numbers is: ${productOfArray(firstNOddNums)}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let multOdd = (n) => {
    let total = 1;
    for (let i = 1; i<= 2*n; i+=2){
        total *= i;
    }
    return total;
}

console.log(multOdd(10));
```

Comment: i tried what you suggested and if i input N as 3 it will return 7. And 7 is not correct result for 1*3*5 (the first 3 odd numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of recursion, We should use the standard mathematical formula for the product of first n positive odd integers which is

[image: the product of first n positive odd integers] 

Can also be written as (in the form of pi notation) 
                                                                         [image]

For this latex image, I used https://codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php.

Factorial is

```
n! = n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) ... and so on
```

So we can use `Array(n).fill()` to get an array of 10 elements and reduce them to get a factorial by

```
Array(n).fill().reduce((v,_,i) => (i+1) * v || 2)
```

Then we divide it by 2 to the power `n` times the `n!`. Which is what we want. The advantage here is that, this makes your solution, a one liner

```js
let n = 10
let answer = Array(2*n).fill().reduce((v,_,i) => (i+1) * v || 2) / (Math.pow(2,n) * Array(n).fill().reduce((v,_,i) => (i+1) * v || 2))
console.log(answer)
```